# Counting computer login times for the week

Tags: windows, logging, authentication

I am probably asking this question in the wrong place (Maybe I should go to an OS forum) - but I still want to know this.

I am using a windows- 7 machine for my work. I log in everyday, do some work and then log off. I take a few short breaks in between when I Lock (Windows+L) my laptop.

I have to account for the number of hours worked by the end of the week which means the time for which I was logged in to this machine.

The problem is that I do complete all the work that is assigned to me, but I forget to keep track of the exact hours I was logged into this machine. I may have logged in at 5 am in the morning and then logged off at 3 in the afternoon- and I dont have any manual logs of my time.

Is there someplace where windows keep a weekly track of

Say per day:

"The Latest log-off time - The Earliest Log in time" into that system for a particular day. I only need these logs for a week.

any heads up would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to solve this problem for years, but only recently found a solution that:

1. May be implemented without administrative privileges
2. Does not require extra software

Kudos to [Guiding Tech](https://www.guidingtech.com/6068/track-work-time-login-lock-task-schedule/) for providing the solution shown below. Change the suggested folder and filenames as you desire, but adjust the batch file code and Task Scheduler commands accordingly.

## Part One: Create the script

1. Create the folder where you would like the script and text log file of login and lock/logoff to reside. For this example, I will presume the desired folder is "C:!Scripts\Login\"
2. Create a new text file in the folder and name it login.bat. A quick way to do this is to right-click a blank space in the folder view, and select **New > Text Document**, then name it *login.bat*.
3. Open the text file and copy and paste in the following code:

   ```
   echo off    
   set datecode=%date:~-4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
   if "%1"=="i" echo %datecode% - Logged in >> C:\!Scripts\Login\login.txt
   if "%1"=="o" echo %datecode% - Locked computer >> C:\!Scripts\Login\login.txt
   ```
4. Save the new batch file

## Part Two: Create the login task

1. Open Task Scheduler. Press the Windows key, and then type "Task Scheduler" and click on the application that appears with that name. Alternatively, use **Start > Run** (**Win + R**), type *taskschd.msc* and press Enter.
2. Select **Create Task...** from the actions on the right hand side
3. Enter a task name like "Log the login date and time"
4. Click on the **Triggers** tab and add a new trigger. Select:

   - Begin the task: *At log on*
   - Specific user: This should be your Windows account name.
   - Click OK to add the trigger.
5. Add another trigger, except this time select **Begin the task: On workstation unlock**. Click OK to add the trigger.
6. Click on the **Actions** tab. Add a new action and point it to your login script with the argument **i**. 
   [image]

Click OK to add the action.
7. (Optional – Only required if you are using a laptop) Click on the **Conditions** tab and uncheck the box that says *Start the task only if the computer is on AC power*. Click on **OK** to create the task.

## Part Three: Create the lock task

1. In Task Scheduler, select **Create Task…** from the actions on the right hand side.
2. Enter a task name like *Log the lock date and time*.
3. Click on the **Triggers** tab and add a new trigger. Select:

   - Begin the task: *On workstation lock*
   - Specific user: This should be your Windows account
   - Click OK to add the trigger.
4. Click on the **Actions** tab. Add a new action and point it to your login script with the argument **o**.
   [image]

Click OK to add the action.

5. (Optional – Only required if you are using a laptop) Click on the **Conditions** tab and uncheck the box that says *Start the task only if the computer is on AC power.* Click on OK to create the task.

## Part Four: Testing that everything is working as expected

Your work is now complete. You just need to test that everything is working as expected. Just lock your computer by hitting **WIN+L** and log back in. If you followed the instructions properly, you should now have a file called login.txt in the same folder as your script. This file should contain a log of each time you log in and out of your computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event log to check when you logged in and logged put (or locked the PC for that matter) but you would have to do that by hand.. You could write a program to do that but that would be hard.

BTW: You will need to enable a group policy or something to enable login events. Have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx)