# How do I view login history for my PC using Windows 7

Tags: authentication, login-script

1. Start->“eventvwr”.
2. Then expanding  Windows Logs, I have selected  Security.
3. But I did not get proper details of login history.

Comment: What details are you getting?

Comment: Might be a better fit for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

The event viewer (eventvwr.exe) contains some relevant records but you would need to create your own logon/logon script through a policy in order to maintain suitable records, e.g. like so:
@echo off
if not exist c:\Logs md c:\Logs
echo Logon: %date% %time:~0,5% %UserName% >> c:\Logs\History.txt

From -> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-i-view-login-history-for-my-pc-using/a0172887-1071-47fb-b0a3-6ca9360efdbf?auth=1

Comment: Details of how to set up an automatic history log of login/logon, lock and logoff times are provided at the Stackoverflow answer [Counting computer login times for the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692600/counting-computer-login-times-for-the-week/46989739#46989739)